# XML code for import Receipt voucher into tally ERP

Tags: java, .net, xml

The code used to import a receipt voucher into tally ERP and the problem is after imported the BRS page should not show the content for bank reconciliation. If anybody know the solution for this problem please help me.

```
<VOUCHER REMOTEID="" VCHTYPE="Receipt" ACTION="Create" OBJVIEW="Accounting Voucher View">
        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
           <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
        </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
    <DATE>20160912</DATE>
    <GUID/>
    <NARRATION>being EMI collected for the month of September, 2016</NARRATION>
    <TAXUNITNAME>Default Tax Unit</TAXUNITNAME>
    <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Receipt</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
    <VOUCHERNUMBER>179</VOUCHERNUMBER>
    <PARTYLEDGERNAME>2016200288 Dr&apos;s Led B Divya Darshini&#13;&#10;</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
    <CSTFORMISSUETYPE/>
    <CSTFORMRECVTYPE/>
    <FBTPAYMENTTYPE>Default</FBTPAYMENTTYPE>
    <PERSISTEDVIEW>Accounting Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
    <VCHGSTCLASS/>
    <ENTEREDBY>manoj</ENTEREDBY>      
    <EFFECTIVEDATE>20160912</EFFECTIVEDATE>
    <HASCASHFLOW>Yes</HASCASHFLOW>
    <ENTEREDBY>SYSTEM</ENTEREDBY>

    <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
    <LEDGERNAME>2016200288 Dr&apos;s Led B Divya Darshini&#13;&#10;</LEDGERNAME>
    <GSTCLASS/>
    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <AMOUNT>1692</AMOUNT>
    <CATEGORY>Chennai Branch</CATEGORY>
    </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>

    <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
        <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST TYPE="Number">
            <OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>-1</OLDAUDITENTRYIDS>
        </OLDAUDITENTRYIDS.LIST>
    <LEDGERNAME>ABC Bank Ltd- A/c No.1234567890</LEDGERNAME>
    <GSTCLASS/>
    <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
    <REMOVEZEROENTRIES>No</REMOVEZEROENTRIES>
    <ISPARTYLEDGER>Yes</ISPARTYLEDGER>
    <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
    <AMOUNT>-1692</AMOUNT>
    <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
            <DATE>20160912</DATE>
            <INSTRUMENTDATE></INSTRUMENTDATE>
            <NAME>757a0139-500d-4431-9557-9faa864bada7</NAME>
            <TRANSACTIONTYPE>Cheque/DD</TRANSACTIONTYPE>
            <PAYMENTFAVOURING>2016200288 Dr&apos;s Led B Divya Darshini&#13;&#10;</PAYMENTFAVOURING>
            <UNIQUEREFERENCENUMBER>3IwbWyz4z226QiK8</UNIQUEREFERENCENUMBER>
            <PAYMENTMODE>Transacted</PAYMENTMODE>
            <STATUS>No</STATUS>
            <CHEQUEPRINTED> 1</CHEQUEPRINTED>
            <AMOUNT>-1692</AMOUNT>
    </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
    </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
    </VOUCHER>

    </TALLYMESSAGE>
    </REQUESTDATA>
    </IMPORTDATA>

        </BODY>

    </ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: This code has sensitive information like  Name-Bank Name-Account Number. My suggestion is to always revisit the pasted code and edit it with some temp values. And not directly copy paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<IMPORTDATA>
 <REQUESTDESC>
<REPORTNAME>Vouchers</REPORTNAME>
<STATICVARIABLES>
 <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Abc</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</REQUESTDESC>
<REQUESTDATA>
<TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF='TallyUDF'>
 <VOUCHER REMOTEID='remote id' VCHKEY='25636997-4ba8-bbe7-9cc74518a9c5-        0000a748:00000000' VCHTYPE='Receipt' ACTION='Create' OBJVIEW='Accounting Voucher View'>
  <DATE>{$_POST["date"]}</DATE>
  <GUID>25636997-ae8d-4ba8-bbe7-9cc74518a9c5-00000000</GUID>
  <NARRATION>{$_POST["narration"]}</NARRATION>
  <VOUCHERTYPENAME>{$_POST['Vname']}</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
  <VOUCHERNUMBER>{$_POST['Vnumber']}</VOUCHERNUMBER>
  <CSTFORMISSUETYPE/>
  <CSTFORMRECVTYPE/>
  <PERSISTEDVIEW>Accounting Voucher View</PERSISTEDVIEW>
  <VCHGSTCLASS/>
  <DIFFACTUALQTY>No</DIFFACTUALQTY>
  <ASORIGINAL>No</ASORIGINAL>
  <FORJOBCOSTING>No</FORJOBCOSTING>
  <ISOPTIONAL>No</ISOPTIONAL>
  <EFFECTIVEDATE>{$_POST["Edate"]}</EFFECTIVEDATE>
  <USEFOREXCISE>No</USEFOREXCISE>
  <USEFORINTEREST>No</USEFORINTEREST>
  <USEFORGAINLOSS>No</USEFORGAINLOSS>
  <USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>No</USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>
  <USEFORCOMPOUND>No</USEFORCOMPOUND>
  <USEFORSERVICETAX>No</USEFORSERVICETAX>
  <EXCISETAXOVERRIDE>No</EXCISETAXOVERRIDE>
  <ISTDSOVERRIDDEN>No</ISTDSOVERRIDDEN>
  <ISTCSOVERRIDDEN>No</ISTCSOVERRIDDEN>
  <ISVATOVERRIDDEN>No</ISVATOVERRIDDEN>
  <ISSERVICETAXOVERRIDDEN>No</ISSERVICETAXOVERRIDDEN>
  <ISEXCISEOVERRIDDEN>No</ISEXCISEOVERRIDDEN>
  <ISCANCELLED>No</ISCANCELLED>
  <HASCASHFLOW>No</HASCASHFLOW>
  <ISPOSTDATED>No</ISPOSTDATED>
  <USETRACKINGNUMBER>No</USETRACKINGNUMBER>
  <ISINVOICE>No</ISINVOICE>
  <MFGJOURNAL>No</MFGJOURNAL>
  <HASDISCOUNTS>No</HASDISCOUNTS>
  <ASPAYSLIP>No</ASPAYSLIP>
  <ISCOSTCENTRE>No</ISCOSTCENTRE>
  <ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>No</ISSTXNONREALIZEDVCH>
  <ISBLANKCHEQUE>No</ISBLANKCHEQUE>
  <ISVOID>No</ISVOID>
  <ISONHOLD>No</ISONHOLD>
  <ORDERLINESTATUS>No</ORDERLINESTATUS>
  <ISDELETED>No</ISDELETED>
  <EXCLUDEDTAXATIONS.LIST>      </EXCLUDEDTAXATIONS.LIST>
  <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>      </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
  <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>      </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
  <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>      </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
  <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>      </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
  <SUPPLEMENTARYDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>                           </SUPPLEMENTARYDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
  <INVOICEDELNOTES.LIST>      </INVOICEDELNOTES.LIST>
  <INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>      </INVOICEORDERLIST.LIST>
  <INVOICEINDENTLIST.LIST>      </INVOICEINDENTLIST.LIST>
  <ATTENDANCEENTRIES.LIST>      </ATTENDANCEENTRIES.LIST>
  <ORIGINVOICEDETAILS.LIST>      </ORIGINVOICEDETAILS.LIST>
  <INVOICEEXPORTLIST.LIST>      </INVOICEEXPORTLIST.LIST>
  <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
   <LEDGERNAME>{$_POST["Lname"]}</LEDGERNAME>
   <GSTCLASS/>
   <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
   <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
   <ISPARTYLEDGER>No</ISPARTYLEDGER>
   <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
   <AMOUNT>-{$_POST["Vamount"]}</AMOUNT>
   <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
   <CATEGORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </CATEGORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
    <DATE>{$_POST["date"]}</DATE>
    <INSTRUMENTDATE>{$_POST["Idate"]}</INSTRUMENTDATE>
    <NAME>dadd2b23-ed51-47cf-a3a8-b5c29b6061c8</NAME>
    <TRANSACTIONTYPE>{$_POST["Ttype"]}</TRANSACTIONTYPE>
    <PAYMENTFAVOURING>{$_POST["Lname2"]}</PAYMENTFAVOURING>
    <TRANSACTIONNAME/>
    <UNIQUEREFERENCENUMBER>3NaCH7BHvhd0vbES</UNIQUEREFERENCENUMBER>
    <STATUS>No</STATUS>
    <PAYMENTMODE>{$_POST["mode"]}</PAYMENTMODE>
    <BANKPARTYNAME>{$_POST["Lname2"]}</BANKPARTYNAME>
    <CHEQUEPRINTED> 1</CHEQUEPRINTED>
    <AMOUNT>-{$_POST["Vamount"]}</AMOUNT>
    <CONTRACTDETAILS.LIST>        </CONTRACTDETAILS.LIST>
   </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>       </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
   <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
   <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
   <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
   <INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>       </INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>
   <INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
   <EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
   <SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>       </SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>
   <STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>       </STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>
   <EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>       </VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
   <REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>       </REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>
   <INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>       </INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>
   <VATITCDETAILS.LIST>       </VATITCDETAILS.LIST>
  </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
  <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
   <LEDGERNAME>{$_POST["Lname2"]}</LEDGERNAME>
   <VOUCHERFBTCATEGORY/>
   <GSTCLASS/>
   <ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
   <LEDGERFROMITEM>No</LEDGERFROMITEM>
   <ISPARTYLEDGER>No</ISPARTYLEDGER>
   <ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISLASTDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
   <AMOUNT>{$_POST["Vamount"]}</AMOUNT>
   <SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>       </SERVICETAXDETAILS.LIST>
   <CATEGORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </CATEGORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </BANKALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>       </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
   <OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </OLDAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
   <ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </ACCOUNTAUDITENTRIES.LIST>
   <AUDITENTRIES.LIST>       </AUDITENTRIES.LIST>
   <INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>       </INPUTCRALLOCS.LIST>
   <INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </DUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
   <EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>       </EXCISEDUTYHEADDETAILS.LIST>
   <SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>       </SUMMARYALLOCS.LIST>
   <STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>       </STPYMTDETAILS.LIST>
   <EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </EXCISEPAYMENTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXBILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TAXOBJECTALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>       </TDSEXPENSEALLOCATIONS.LIST>
   <VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>       </VATSTATUTORYDETAILS.LIST>
   <REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>       </REFVOUCHERDETAILS.LIST>
   <INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>       </INVOICEWISEDETAILS.LIST>
   <VATITCDETAILS.LIST>       </VATITCDETAILS.LIST>
  </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
  <VCHLEDTOTALTREE.LIST>      </VCHLEDTOTALTREE.LIST>
  <PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>      </PAYROLLMODEOFPAYMENT.LIST>
  <ATTDRECORDS.LIST>      </ATTDRECORDS.LIST>
  </VOUCHER>
  </TALLYMESSAGE>
  </REQUESTDATA>
  </IMPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
  </ENVELOPE>
```